# Is there a userpage for all of stackexchange?

Tags: feature-request, stack-exchange, reputation-leagues

I'm curious to see the top users by sum of reputation across all sites in a single userpage, as though it were one site.

I see the [leagues](https://stackexchange.com/leagues), but those still sort by site.

Of course the top users of Stack Overflow would dominate such a list, but it would still be interesting to find users actively participating at the upper ends of many sites.

What I would like is a page just like https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users but for all of Stack Exchange, where I can sort by time range, new users, etc, but over all the sites, with the user reputation being the sum of each user's reputation, the badges being the sum of the badges across all sites, etc.

The [Stack Exchange flair](https://stackexchange.com/users/flair/2114.png) already includes multiple sites and the total reputation.

Eventually it'd be interesting to have a Stack Exchange Generalist badge awarded to those who are in the top x% of several sites.

But first I'd like to get an idea what the Stack Exchange userbase looks like as a whole, and the existing methods don't seem to support this.

Comment: On a related note, a weighted user page would be interesting (ex. 2k on, say, Aviation would count more than 20k on SO). Perhaps this could be done by percentile. Anyway, +1 because good idea.

Comment: I couldn't care one way or the other about the OP, but this did have the brilliant effect of linking me via related questions to Atwood's classic answer on [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65506/could-an-opt-in-stackexchange-globally-merged-site-save-us-from-all-the-merge?rq=1), which made my day :)

Comment: This is cool idea. thanksss!

Comment: @Doorknob That could be interesting, but it'd be difficult to do right.  I may be in the top 0.01% of a site with little traffic, but have only had to put in a few dozen hours, whereas a user on stackoverflow may have put in thousands of hours, gets lots of votes, but still isn't in the top 1%.  I'd say just start out with raw rep as a metric for now, and explore other rankings later.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what the current process is, but wasn't there a global stackexchange meta site in process to give mSO its own place? I would imagine that the users on mSE would encompass everyone from all sites.